# Segment Description in Financials is populated with CONSERVATION Management- DEFAULTDEFAULT

Tags: bi-publisher

I have create a BIP report (rtf) in Microsoft via add-ins. The Segment Description is populated with different descriptions e.g. CONSERVATION-Management-DEFAULT-DEFAULT how do I get rid of the -DEFAULT-DEFAULT at the end of the string?

So far I have tried  and managed to get it down to CONSERVATION-Management-DEFAUL but it still is displaying the -DEFAUL at the end.

Comment: <?xdofx:rtrim(substr(CF_SEGMENTS_DESCRIPTION,12,30))?>

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You can edit your original question. It is better to do that than add comments folks may not see when reading your question.